# Spark Framework CSRF Protection

Tags: java, rest, csrf-protection, spark-framework

I'm developping a REST-Service with the Spark Framework. So far i haven't found any possibility to implement CSRF Protection.

Is there the possibility to implement CSRF Protection using integrated functions? Or do i have to use external modules like [Pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spark-pac4j)?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, and it is really easy to implement. All you need is to add a custom Filter.

```
before((request, response) -> {
    List<String> safeMethods = Arrays.asList("GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD");
    if (!safeMethods.contains(request.requestMethod())) {
        if (!request.headers().contains("X-Requested-By")) {
            halt(400);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `X-Requested-With`